# sum with a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

There are 3 tables:

```
Suppl, fields: (Code_name,  Tasknum, Pki_num, Group_eng, Name, Descr, Cost, Quan, shop)
Maker, fields : (Code_maker, Code_maker_arch, Code_name, provider)
Arrival, fields: (Code_arr, Code_maker, quan_arr)
```

I need to get a table (for export to Excel), for example update_501 (Group_eng, Name, Descr, quan_arr), which will contain a unique "Descr" by a group_eng_501. The field "quan_arr" needs to keep the sum of the field from the table Arrival.quan_arr for each unique "Descr".

first:

```
Insert dbo.update_501(Group_eng, Name, Descr)
select Group_eng, Name, Descr
from Suppl
where (Group_eng = 501)
group by Group_eng, Name, Descr
```

then:
trigger, which adds a unique "descr" to update_501

```
ALTER trigger [update_pki_501] ON [dbo].[Suppl]
After Insert
as
begin
Set nocount on;
if (not(exists(select * from [INSERTED])))
return;

Insert dbo.update_501(Group_eng, Name, Descr)
select I.Name
      ,I.Descr
      ,I.Group_eng
from Inserted I
where (I.Group_eng = 501)
 and not exists(select * from dbo.update_501 x where x.Group_eng=I.Group_eng and x.Descr = I.Descr) 
end
```

Please, help with a trigger that will add(and sum) in the update_501.quan_arr from Arrival.quan_arr

Comment: There are literally over 100 different products that speak SQL. Those that are RDBMS's and have triggers don't all have the same syntax for creating and defining them. You must tag your question with the RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you are not wanting to calculate the sum while inserting into the table given that your trigger is for inserts only.

Presumably you could just

```
INSERT update_501 (Group_eng, Name, Descr, quan_arr) 
SELECT s.Group_eng, s.Name, s.Descr, Sum(a.Quan_Arr) 
FROM   Suppl s
  JOIN Maker m ON s.Code_Name = m.Code_Name
  JOIN Arrival a ON m.Code_Maker = a.Code_Maker
WHERE  --  if a where clause is needed  
GROUP BY s.Group_eng, s.Name, s.Descr
--HAVING --if a having clause is appropriate
```

After inserting it, if you want to update it when a new Arrival is inserted, then you'd need an insert trigger for the Arrival table something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Arrival_update_501 ON dbo.Arrival
AFTER INSERT
AS Begin
  Set nocount on;
  if (not(exists(select * from Inserted)))
    return;

  DECLARE @Group_eng  <datatype>, 
          @Name       <datatype?, 
          @Descr      <datatype>;
  DECLARE @tbl        table (
    Group_Eng         <datatype>,
    Name              <datatype>,
    Descr             <datatype>
  );

  INSERT @tbl
  SELECT s.Group_Eng, s.Name, s.Descr
  FROM   Suppl s
    JOIN Maker m ON s.Code_Name = m.Code_Name
    JOIN Inserted i ON m.Code_Maker = i.Code_Maker;

  UPDATE u
  SET    quan_arr = newTotal.quan_sum
  FROM   update_501 u
      JOIN @tbl t ON u.Group_Eng = t.Group_Eng AND u.Name = t.Name AND u.Descr = t.Descr
      JOIN Suppl s    ON u.Group_Eng = s.Group_Eng
      JOIN (
          SELECT m.Code_Name, Sum(a.quan_arr) as quan_sum
          FROM   Maker m JOIN Arrival a ON m.Code_Maker = a.Code_Maker
          ) newTotal;
END
```

NB: I may have misunderstood the joins between your tables. It will help you to get better answers if you translate your table structures into easily understood naming in your questions. Eg

```
Suppl (Suppl_ID, ...)
Maker (Maker_ID, ..., Suppl_ID)
etc
```

Comment: Suppl(Suppl_ID, ...) ; Maker (Maker_ID, ..., Suppl_ID); Arrival(Arrival_id, ..., Maker_id). group_eng - int; name, descr - varchar